# Issue with SQLite DROP TABLE statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pysqlite

EDIT: At this point, I found the errant typo that was responsible, and my question has become "How did the typo that I made cause the error that I received" and "How might I have better debugged this in the future?"

I've setup a database script for SQLite (through pysqlite) as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LandTerritory;
CREATE TABLE LandTerritory (
  name   varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
  hasSC  boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

I'm expecting this to always run without error.  However, if I run this script twice, (using the `sqlite.Connection.executescript` method) I get this error:
`OperationalError:table LandTerritory already exists`

Trying to debug this myself, I run `DROP TABLE LandTerritory` on its own and get:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: main.LandTerrito`

I'm guessing this has something to do with the "main." part, but I'm not sure what.

EDIT:
Okay `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON` is definitely involved here, too.  When I create my connection, I turned on foreign_keys.  If I don't turn that on, I don't seem to get this error.

And I should have mentioned that there's more to the script, but I had assumed the error was occurring in these first 2 statements.  The rest of the script just does the same, drop table, define table.  A few of the tables have foreign key references to `LandTerritory`.

Is there a way to get something like line number information about the sqlite errors?  That would be really helpful.

EDIT 2:
Okay, here's another table in the script that references the first.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LandAdjacent;
CREATE TABLE LandAdjacent (
  tname1 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  tname2 varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (tname1, tname2),
  /* Foreign keys */
  FOREIGN KEY (tname1)
    REFERENCES LandTerrito
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE, 
  FOREIGN KEY (tname2)
    REFERENCES LandTerritory(name)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Looking at this, I found were the "LandTerrito" came from, somehow a few characters got cut off.  I'm guessing fixing this may fix my problem.

But I'm really confused how a broken line in this table led to the script running correctly the first time, and then giving me an error related to a different table when I run it the second time, and how foreign keys played into this.

I guess, to reiterate from above, is there a better way to debug this sort of thing?

Comment: I know you made it clear how the script works, but just to be certain, can you post it, or at least the relevant parts?

Answer (score 1):

The source of the error is your typo

```
REFERENCES LandTerrito
```

in line 8 of your script. This leads to the "missing" table `LandTerrito` in the `CREATE TABLE LandAdjacent` statement.

If you run your two `CREATE TABLE` statements Sqlite wont complain. But if you have `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;` and try to run an `INSERT` or `DELETE` statement on the table `LandAdjacent`, you'll get the error `no such table: main.LandTerrito`.

Because of the foreign key constraints `DROP TABLE` on `LandTerritory` however will result in a `DELETE` on the table `LandAdjacent`, which triggers the error.

The following things will avoid the error

1. set `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;` before you drop the table (tested) or
2. add a dummy table `LandTerrito` (tested) or
3. drop `LandAdjacent` first, then `LandTerritory` (tested) or
4. dont use `ON DELETE CASCADE` (not tested)
5. and of course correcting the original typo.

Answer (score -2):

Put a "GO" (or whatever equivalent is used in SQLlite) to terminate a batch between the drop table statement and the create statement